# scala absolute min distance between words in a text

Tags: scala, functional-programming, match, distance, min

I'm trying to find the min distance between multiple words in a given text.

Let's suppose I a string such as: "**a b cat dog x y z n m p fox x dog b b cat**"

Find the min distance of all matches of substrings: (fox, dog, cat)

there are multiple occurrences of each substring in this text:

- one at the beginning:

cat - 4
dog - 8
fox - 24

dist = 24 - 4 = 20

- And one at the end of string:

fox - 24
dog - 30
cat - 38

dist = 38 - 24 = 14

the **min Dist = 14**

This is the algorithm I came up with:

```
 object MinKWindowSum {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {   

    val document =
      """This Hello World is a huge text with thousands
Java of Hello words and Scala other lines and World and many other Hello docs
Words of World in many langs Hello and features
Java Scala AXVX TXZX ASDQWE OWEQ World asb eere qwerer
asdasd Scala Java Hello docs World KLKM NWQEW ZXCASD OPOOIK Scala ASDSA
"""
    println(getMinWindowSize(document, "Hello World Scala"))
  }   

  def getMinWindowSize(str:String, s:String): Int = {

    /* creates a list of tuples List[(String, Int)] which contains each keyword and its
    respective index found in the text sorted in order by index.
    */
    val keywords = s.split(" ").toSet
    val idxs = keywords.map(k => (k -> ("(?i)\\Q" + k + "\\E").r.findAllMatchIn(str).map(_.start)))
      .map{ case (keyword,itr) => itr.map((keyword, _))}
      .flatMap(identity).toSeq
      .sortBy(_._2)

    // Calculates the min window on the next step.
    var min = Int.MaxValue
    var minI, minJ = -1

    // current window indexes and words
    var currIdxs = ListBuffer[Int]()
    var currWords = ListBuffer[String]()

    for(idx <- idxs ) {

      // check if word exists in window already
      val idxOfWord = currWords.indexOf(idx._1)

      if (!currWords.isEmpty && idxOfWord != -1) {
        currWords = currWords.drop(idxOfWord + 1)
        currIdxs = currIdxs.drop(idxOfWord + 1)
      }
      currWords += idx._1
      currIdxs += idx._2

      // if all keys are present check if it is new min window
      if (keywords.size == currWords.length) {
        val currMin = Math.abs(currIdxs.last - currIdxs.head)
        if (min > currMin) {
          min = currMin
          minI = currIdxs.head
          minJ = currIdxs.last
        }
      }
    }

    println("min = " + min + " ,i = " + minI + " j = " + minJ)
    min
  }

}
```

In the example above we try to find the min distance between all matches of "Hello World Scala"

The shortest window between the indexes is found between indexes:
**i = 235, j = 257 --> min = 22**

Was wondering if there is a better way of doing this in an idiomatic way or in a better manner in terms of efficiency, scalability, readability and simplicity?

Comment: I think `something.foldLeft(List[...]())((result, x) => result :+ f(x)))` is also known as `something.map(f(_))`.

Comment: Also, `something.foldLeft(List[...]())((result, x) => result ++ x)` seems to me the same thing as `something.flatMap(identity)`.

Comment: For readability's sake, `for (tuple <- idxs)` should be `for ((keyword, num) <- idxs)` and then `tuple._1` could be eliminated. I'd go with a trivial data class instead of a tuple, just to avoid `._1` and the like.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly "more functional" alternative:

```
val document =
  """This Hello World is a huge text with thousands Java of Hello words and Scala other lines and World and many other Hello docs
     Words of World in many langs Hello and features Java Scala AXVX TXZX ASDQWE OWEQ World
  """
val WORDS = Set("Hello", "World", "Scala")

var minDistance = document.trim
  .split(" ")
  .foldLeft(List[(String, Int)](), None: Option[Int], 0) {
    case ((words, min, idx), word) if WORDS.contains(word) =>
      val newWords = (word, idx) :: words.filter(_._1 != word)
      if (newWords.map(_._1).toSet == WORDS) { // toSet on only 3 elmts
        var idxes = newWords.map(_._2)
        var dist = idxes.max - idxes.min
        var newMin = min match {
          case None                    => dist
          case Some(min) if min < dist => min
          case _                       => dist
        }
        (newWords, Some(newMin), idx + word.length + 1)
      }
      else {
        (newWords, min, idx + word.length + 1)
      }
    case ((words, min, idx), word) =>
      (words, min, idx + word.length + 1)
  }
  ._2

println(minDistance)
```

which produces:

```
Some(38)
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach starts with a similar premise but uses a tail-recursive helper method to search the indexed words.

```
def getMinWindowSize(str :String, s :String) :Int = {
  val keywords = s.split("\\s+").toSet
  val re = "(?i)\\b(" + keywords.mkString("|") + ")\\b"
  val idxs = re.r.findAllMatchIn(str).map(w => w.start -> w.toString).toList

  def dist(input :List[(Int, String)], keys :Set[String]) :Option[Int] = input match {
    case Nil => None
    case (idx, word) :: rest =>
      if (keys(word) && keys.size == 1) Some(idx)
      else dist(rest, keys diff Set(word))
  }

  idxs.tails.collect{
    case (idx, word)::rest => dist(rest, keywords diff Set(word)).map(_ - idx)
  }.flatten.reduceOption(_ min _).getOrElse(-1)
}
```

No mutable variables or data structures. I also used `Option` to help return a more meaningful value if no minimum window is possible.

Usage:

```
getMinWindowSize(document, "Hello World Scala")  //res0: Int = 22
getMinWindowSize(document, "Hello World Scal")   //res1: Int = -1
```